# VB Excel - Print set columns on diff pages

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have been given a very ugly excel document which I need to be able to print the first 4 columns off every time and then loop through each of the next columns so they only print one at a time per sheet as if the first 4 columns were frozen and then each of the others prints off one at a time in turn.

I have tired a number of different approaches to this from hide, unhide to looping and active cells but I cant seem to find the best and most efficient effect way to do it.

The first four columns contain standard headings as titles and then the subsequent ones relate to a specific object - I want to be able to use VB to press a button and print out the heading columns and then effectively each object column on its own page so its like every object has its own page with heading to go into a ring binder file. Hopefully allowing each object to be quickly viewed independently without the data of the other objects if I was viewing the whole spread sheet. Effectively each object on its own page with the default headings, each object is a different column.

I am sure there is a simple way to do this and I am over complicating it!

Any help welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Hide all the columns beginning with Col5.  Loop over the columns: (1) unhide col x (2) Print (3) Hide col x

Comment: have you explored creating views by columns, you will need to setup the views once and then can easily switch between the views. Obviously the pay-off will depend upon how many 'objects' do you have in all, and how frequently will you be making use of these views?